# How to Move from Google Play Music to Plex Music

Tags: google-play, plex

This is for anyone else who, like me, is mourning the sad, [soon-coming death of Google Play (Music)](https://www.pcmag.com/news/rip-google-play-music-users-told-to-migrate-to-youtube-music) and annoyed w/the forced moved to YouTube Music. The question/goal I had was simply "how do I move from Google Play (Music) to Plex Music?" so I figured I'd share my notes/steps here in case anyone else finds it helpful. *Reminder: Once Google Play is turned off officially (date unknown, end of 2020?) you won't be able to perform some or all of these steps anymore.*

Answer (score 2):

#### 1) Download Your Music from Google

Use [Google's "Music Manager" app](https://downloads.tomsguide.com/Music-Manager,0301-48996.html) to download your entire library to your hard drive somewhere.
While you can download your music from Google Play using the Chrome "Google Play" extension I don't recommend if you can avoid it because it's buggy and it doesn't make Artist and Album folders for you like the "Music Manager" app does which, IMHO, is helpful vs a folder w/thousands of unorganized MP3 files.

(1B) Some people may need to refer to the [pycryptodomex docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-from-sources-python-3-5-and-newer) if they encounter compiler issues with gmusicapi and plexapi. Thanks to Paul for the heads up.

#### 2) Setup Plex Music Library

Assuming you have a Plex server setup and running, create a "[Plex Music](https://www.plex.tv/your-media/music/)" library item and pick the folder(s) it should use. Once this is done, copy all your music from step #1 above to it, tell Plex to scan the folders and wait for it to finish scanning everything. Confirm all your albums/artists show up, in general, as they did in Google Play (Music).

#### 3) Pull Google Play (Music) Playlists into Plex Music

*Reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/PleX/comments/hfgnvk/import_google_play_music_playlists/*

1. [Install python for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows) (if not installed already)
2. Run this in a command prompt to install the python script dependencies:
   `python -m pip install --upgrade pip gmusicapi plexapi requests`
3. [Download copy of this python script here](https://gist.github.com/sdlynx/75289f657995cb28bae7f9ba5a48b867)
4. Get these 3 things from your Plex server:

- Plex URL (e.g. http://10.10.1.10:32400)
- Active Plex Token via [these instructions](https://support.plex.tv/articles/204059436-finding-an-authentication-token-x-plex-token/)
- Name of the Plex Music library you're importing your Google playlists to

5. Add the 3 Plex items from #4 above to the top of your copy of the python script and save the file.
6. Run your copy of the python script in a command prompt: `python gmusic_playlists_to_plex.py`
7. Follow prompt instructions to authenticate on Google and watch the magic happen
   *(You may have to run it a second time after authenticating if it throws an error on first try)*

Note: A few of my playlists were mangled a bit (maybe due to deleted songs or metadata oddities but fortunately most of my most-recent/most-used playlists copied over fine.

#### 4) Enjoy Plex Music!

While I know maintaining a music locally (via Plex) will require hard drive/backup maintenance work over time, I have to say I am loving Plex Music so far. There seems to be a bug w/the offline sync (w/the iOS app) but I'm sure they'll fix and aside from that the entire library/playlist/queue experience in Plex Music is actually faster and better than Google Play (IMHO) - loving it so far. I also just discovered today that they have a cool new iOS app dedicated entirely to the music stuff that seems even better than the Google Play iOS app: [Plexamp](https://plexamp.com/).

Thanks again to the Reddit guys for elements in #3. LMK if I left anything important out or should add a step.

Comment: pycryptodomex (a dependency for gmusicapi and plexapi) requires a compiler on Windows. Could you add an optional step 1b) for this? See [pycryptodomex docs](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/installation.html#windows-from-sources-python-3-5-and-newer)

Comment: I am finding massive issues with step (2). It seems Plex does NOT reliably read ID3 tag data and requires albums / artists to be expressed as a nested folder structure rather than the flat structure you get from Google Takeout. How did you solve that? I've spent 2 hours tinkering with Music library options (agents, scanners, etc, etc) and it is shockingly complicated and does not work out of the box. :(

Comment: @Creos Sorry to hear man - yeah some things didn't migrate perfectly (some albums have tracks duplicated, some ID3 stuff off bit) but the majority of my library seems fine. Good luck! FWIW I love being free of Google - Plex music is far better if you can swing it.